# Laravel form links to wrong controller function

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make a login page for 2 actor, first actor is calon and second actor is bph. It looks like this

[image: login page]

The button Login BPH is supposed to link to login_bph function in LoginController and button Login Calon Pengurus Osis is supposed to link to login_calon function in LoginController. This is the code from LoginController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Validator;

class loginController extends Controller
{
    public function login_bph(Request $req){
        $email = $req->input('email');
        $password = $req->input('password');

        $checkLogin = DB::table('users')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();
        if(count($checkLogin)>0){
            // return redirect()->intended('homepage');
            echo "login bph berhasil";
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/')->withInput();
        }
    }

    public function login_calon(Request $req){
        $email = $req->input('email');
        $password = $req->input('password');

        $checkLogin = DB::table('users')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();
        if(count($checkLogin)>0){
            // return redirect()->intended('homepage');
            echo "login calon berhasil";
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/')->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

But somehow when I test to login with the button Login Calon Pengurus Osis, it headed to login_bph function in the LoginController. I already set up the right route but it get that kind of error. This is the route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.login');
});
Route::post('/login_bph','loginController@login_bph');
Route::post('/login_calon','loginController@login_calon');
```

And I think it's because of the action tag in the login form that makes this error, I need both submit buttons to link to each function they are supposed to link with but I don't know how to make it happen. I need it to be with same form but the buttons to link to each function they are supposed to link with. Sorry for the bad English. This is the form

```
<form id="msform" action="/login_bph" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"> </span></span>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="•••••••••••" name="password" required>
    </div>
     <br>   
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="login_bph" value="Login BPH">
     <form id="msform" action="/login_calon" method="post">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="login_calon" value="Login Calon Pengurus Osis">
     </form>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is you are nesting  inside . This is not allowed. You can have multiple form but can't have nested.

Answer (score 1):

First you should remove your second form, there shouldn't be a form inside another form.

Then you will need javascript to change your form action based on which button user has clicked. Example in jquery,

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name=login_bph]").on("submit", function(event) {
        $("#msform").attr("action", "/login_bph");
    });

    $("input[name=login_calon]").on("submit", function(event) {
        $("#msform").attr("action", "/login_calon");
    });
});
```